# MYSQL - Get Last messages MAX(time) by users

Tags: mysql, sql

A conversation contains messages and one message can be send to 2 or more users.

The goal is to retrieve the last messages by user for each conversation, so where the messages in each conversation are the newest.

Also the `message_user.time` is when the user has read the message so when it's equals to 0 it's means the message has not been read yet so it'll be even better if the first order will be the message_user where time is equal to 0 and the the message.time that are the biggest numbers.

I got those tables

**Message User**

```
user   message      time   
-----|------------|-------
 7   | 1          | 0
 8   | 1          | 0
 7   | 2          | 300
 8   | 2          | 300
 7   | 3          | 400
```

**Message**

```
id    text         conversation   time
---|-------------|--------------|----------
1  | blah blah1  | 1            | 200
2  | blah blah2  | 1            | 300
3  | blah blah3  | 2            | 400
4  | blah blah4  | 2            | 500
```

The goal is to group the messages by conversation and then get the last message_user linked to that conversation that have the bigger timestamp first.

What i tried is this but i don't get the last messages (wrong order)

```
    SELECT m.user, mu.message, mu.time, mu.id, m.text, m.time as message_time, m.conversation
    FROM message_user as mu,message as m 
    WHERE mu.message=m.id AND mu.user=8
    GROUP BY m.conversation
    ORDER BY m.time DESC';
```

**Then the next step will be:**
I don't know if it's possible but it if the order by can ouput the message_user where the time is equal to 0 first and then second order is message.time (i don't even know if it's possible in one request that will be perfect!)

**For the user 8 the output should be this :**

```
text        conversation 
-----------|------------
blah blah1 | 1         //because message_user.time = 0 (means message is unread)
blah blah3 | 2         //because message.time is the highest in the conversation
```

Thank you !

Comment: That's an odd looking time....

Comment: Could you give some explanations regarding the tables' structure? I mean, what's the goal of Message User table, if each message has only one sender and only one receiver? And what exactly is `conversation`?

Comment: @raina77ow sure do you want me to describe what represent each column?

Comment: @raina77ow ok i will do that ;)

Comment: @raina77ow that's there let me know if you need more info ;)

Comment: Can you give a data sample of the result you are looking for?

Comment: ok i gave the ouput for the user 8 ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'd suggest restructuring your tables to make this easier, but here's what I think you are asking for... Each conversation, showing only the last conversion message created, with the last time and user who read it (but prefer unread over this).

```
SELECT m.user as User_Sent, m.conversation, m.text, m.time as Time_Sent
, mu.id, mu.user as User_Read, mu.time as Time_Read
FROM message as m 
JOIN (
  SELECT mx.conversation, MAX(mx.time) as MaxTime 
  FROM message as mx GROUP BY mx.conversation
  ) as mx
On m.conversation = mx.conversation
And m.time = mx.MaxTime
JOIN (
  SELECT mu.message, MAX(mu.time) as MaxTime, MIN(mu.time) as MinTime 
  From message_user as mu 
  GROUP BY mu.message
) as mux
On m.id = mux.message
JOIN message_user as mu
ON m.id = mu.message
AND CASE WHEN mux.MinTime = 0 THEN mux.MinTime ELSE mux.MaxTime END = mu.time
```

Comment: thank you you just missing a "," on the first line and i got this error: "Unknown column 'mu.MinTime' in 'on clause'" by the way if you have any idea of how i can improve the structure please let me know ;)

Comment: What I'd suggest to fix this up is to have your identifiers (m.id and mu.message) be the same name (like messageId).  Next, you should add a boolean field to mu that is marked true when it has been read.

Comment: Another option would be to change the mu.time field.  Rename it time_read to avoid confusion and then make it nullable, then leave it null until it has been read.  That will probably work better than adding a boolean for when it's been read.

Comment: ok i will make the modifications thank you, yes i will probably break this into many queries to make it simpler as well i think

Comment: No problem.  If you do make it nullable, then you can do an MAX(IFNULL(mu.time,'999999999')) as MaxTime and join on mu.MaxTime = IFNULL(mu.time,'999999999') instead of "CASE WHEN mu.MinTime = 0 THEN mu.MinTime ELSE mu.MaxTime END = mu.time"

Comment: Also I fixed the query so you shouldn't have those unknown column errors.  Sorry.

Comment: ok this time it's working :D Thanks a lot you just missed to select the user 8 but easy to add, ok now i'll try to apply the things you told me for null and renaming my columns may be, thanks again!!!!

Comment: Sorry i just have one last issue, it's not in the right order is it possible to revert the results ?

Comment: You can order the results by adding "ORDER BY " at the bottom and listing what you want to order it by. Just like in your example: "ORDER BY m.time DESC"